# How to sort array of structs by char field so that empty fields go to last place?

Tags: c

I have a struct:

```
struct StructA{
  char name[TEXT_LEN];
  int year;
};
typedef struct StructA Data_t;
```

And lets say that it can be something like:

```
Name: A
Year: 2002

Name: 
Year: 2003

Name: C
Year: 2003

Name: B
Year: 2004

Name: 
Year: 2005
```

Now I would like to sort it in a way that it sorts first existing values and put empty values in last place. For this I use `qsort()`:

```
int compareDataT(const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    const Data_t *u1 = v1;
    const Data_t *u2 = v2;
    return strcmp(u1->name, u2->name);
}

qsort(items, length, sizeof(Data_t), compareDataT);
```

This gives me:

```
Name: 
Year: 2003

Name: 
Year: 2005

Name: A
Year: 2002

Name: B
Year: 2004

Name: C
Year: 2003
```

If I reverse it in function then it gives me `C, B, A, blank, blank`...

I want to have it as `A, B, C, blank, blank`... So, sorted and then put blank values in the end.

I am struggling with this issue for hours... So any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the empty fields to go last, you can modify the comparison function so they compare larger than non empty ones:

```
int compareDataT(const void *v1, const void *v2) {
    const Data_t *u1 = v1;
    const Data_t *u2 = v2;
    if (*u1->name == '\0')
        return (*u2->name == '\0') ? 0 : 1;
    if (*u2->name == '\0')
        return -1;
    return strcmp(u1->name, u2->name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that in any case the data member `name` is initialized and contains at least an empty string `""`.

In this case the comparison function can look like

```
int compareDataT( const void *v1, const void *v2 )
{
    const Data_t *u1 = v1;
    const Data_t *u2 = v2;

    return *u1->name && *u2->name ? strcmp( u1->name, u2->name )
                                  : !*u1->name - !*u2->name;                                                        
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TEXT_LEN    10

struct StructA{
  char name[TEXT_LEN];
  int year;
};
typedef struct StructA Data_t;


int compareDataT( const void *v1, const void *v2 )
{
    const Data_t *u1 = v1;
    const Data_t *u2 = v2;

    return *u1->name && *u2->name ? strcmp( u1->name, u2->name )
                                  : !*u1->name - !*u2->name;                                                        
}

int main(void) 
{
    Data_t data[] = 
    {
        { "", 2020 }, { "A", 2020 }, { "", 2020 }, 
        { "B", 2020 }, { "", 2020 }, { "C", 2020 }
    };
    const size_t N = sizeof( data ) / sizeof( *data );

    qsort( data, N, sizeof( Data_t ), compareDataT );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "{ \"%s\", %d } ", data[i].name, data[i].year );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
{ "A", 2020 } { "B", 2020 } { "C", 2020 } { "", 2020 } { "", 2020 } { "", 2020 }
```